# Matplotlib interfering with NumPy (on Windows)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

<sub>***The issue described below has been replicated***</sub>

---

Say you have the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(5, size=(100, 12), dtype=np.int64)
# [THERE IS ACTUALLY NO NEED TO SET THE DATA TYPE
# `x = np.random.rand(100, 12)` yields the same problem]
```

and you want to compute `x`'s rank.

```
>>> np.linalg.matrix_rank(x)
12
```

Everything is fine. Let's restart a ***new session from scratch***, whose underlying code this time is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1010)  # <-----
x               = np.random.randint(5, size=(100, 12), dtype=np.int64)
x_vals = y_vals = np.arange(0, .5, .05)

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, linestyle='--')

print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(x))
```

This prints `0` (!!). And more surprisingly, the reason behind this is the value given to [`linestyle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) (!!). I mean, having `linestyle='-'` (solid) turns everything back to normal.

This is clearly an undesired behavior (I literally spent hours to locate precisely)... but still:

***How ?***

---

This occurs under Windows 10 with Python3.7.3

```
numpy==1.19.2      # since 1.19.0 actually
matplotlib==3.3.3  # between 3.1.3 and 3.3.3 for what I can tell
```

No problem under Linux (with the same environment)

---

Other precisions

1. This does not occur for all `x`'s shape. Hard to tell exactly. However, this is not random either, and is monotonously linked to `x`'s (vertical and/or horizontal) shape.
2. The issue is transposition-invariant.
3. `x` is exactly the same when compared to itself before `plt.plot` is called (compared using [`joblib.hash`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.hash.html))

---

[image]

---

This question is more about leaving a trace than getting an answer. This is ***so weird*** that ***I had to write it somewhere***. I've changed my `linestyle`...

The title of the question is sufficiently unequivocal to drive people with the same problem as mine here.

---

Another screen capture:

[image]

The GIF's code follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import joblib as jl

linestyles = [
    'solid', '-',
    'dotted',  # '.', => ValueError: '.' 
    'dashed', '--',
    'dashdot', '-.',
    ':', '', ' '    
]

for ls in linestyles:
    print(26*'*', f"linestyle='{ls}'")
    
    np.random.seed(1010)
    x  = np.random.rand(9, 5)
    h0 = jl.hash(x)
    
    x_vals = y_vals = np.arange(0, .5, .05)
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, linestyle=ls)
    # plt.show()
    
    h1 = jl.hash(x)
    mr = np.linalg.matrix_rank(x)
    print(
        '\t', mr, (not mr)*'<---------------[!!!]'
    )
    print('\t', 'Has not changed:', h0 == h1)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224767/discussion-on-question-by-keepalive-matplotlib-interfering-with-numpy-on-window).

Comment: Reported (at least) twice : [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17980) and [there](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18977).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in numpy and has been corrected as of version 1.19.3:

> There is a known problem with Windows 10 version=2004 and OpenBLAS svd
> that we are trying to debug. If you are running that Windows version you
> should use a NumPy version that links to the MKL library, earlier
> Windows versions are fine.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.19.2

> NumPy 1.19.3 is a small maintenace release with two major improvements:
>
> - Python 3.9 binary wheels on all supported platforms.
> - **OpenBLAS fixes for Windows 10 version 2004 fmod bug.**

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.19.3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past too (basically matplotlib not performing as expected).

This was my question:
[python plotting chart in interactive viewer vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536100/python-plotting-chart-in-interactive-viewer-vscode)

Basically, the way the plot is called and when it is finished this is deleted:  "if you close the figure, you're essentially deleting it".

I tend to use the interactive environment (using `python 3.10` in `VScode` on `windows 10`) and this works:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1010)  # <-----
x = np.random.randint(5, size=(100, 12), dtype=np.int64)
x_vals = y_vals = np.arange(0, .5, .05)

x = np.linalg.matrix_rank(x)
print(x)

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

and i get this result (which behaves well):

```
12
```

[image]

Comment: I do not get your point. Even if the problem has been fixed, you cannot reproduce the issue I describe given that you call `np.linalg.matrix_rank` prior to any kind of corruption.

Comment: I can confirm (because i have just tried it) that the same code also works with the `np.linalg.matrix_rank` occuring after the `plt.plot` with the only difference being the order. (chart first, value next)....  so the order did not matter with my config at least.

Comment: Actually @DL, I realized that you got a point here because environment's corruption could potentially have taken place at imports... May be you had this in mind as well, i dunno.

Comment: @keepAlive,  i beleive that it is to do with the way the plot works in different environments (jupyter, interactive, native) as opposed to the imports. That is why changing the order works.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1010)  # <-----

x = np.random.randint(5, size=(100, 12), dtype=np.int64)
x_vals = y_vals = np.arange(0, .5, .05)

x = np.linalg.matrix_rank(x)
print(x)

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you think that your answer is helpful?

Comment: OP didn't ask for code. They obviously can code by themself. They asked for an explanation about why this strange behavior occurs. 
On SO, code only answer are discouraged. But in this case even more than in others, code only answer make no sense at all, since you are sure to give only what was not asked, and not to give any required explanation.