# python plotting chart in interactive viewer vscode

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

This works and shows a plot in `vscode`:

```py
#%% cell with plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [3.2, 3.9, 3.7, 3.5, 3.02199]
x = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
n = [155, "outliner", 293, 230, 670]
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('the x axis')
plt.ylabel('the y axis') 
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
    
plt.show()
```

Here is the image:
[image]

However, this does not work:

```py
#%% call plot separately
plt.show()
```

And neither does this:

```py
#%%  try this too
plt
```

So given that the plot exists (because it can be seen) in the first cell, why can it not be called or seen in the other cells or how can one do this ?

Comment: once you call `show`, if you close the figure, you're essentially deleting it. Why do you need to show it more than once?

Comment: @PaulH,  if the user amends the data in once cell, prepares it etc.   they may wish to plot the new chart in the next cell.  ie. the `plt.show()` could exist elsewhere.  (point taken on closing the figure which deletes it).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**1.** call `plt.ion()` instead of plt.show()

**2.** add `%matplotlib inline` before plt.show()

**3.** uninstall matplotlib and reinstall using `apt-get` instead of pip

**4.** or install this module `apt-get install python3-tk` in addition

Comment: `plt.ion()` works.  question: why is this the case and what is the difference between `plt.ion()` and `plt.show()` ?

Comment: I can't agree #3 and #4. Conda would would be a much better choice that apt-get

Comment: @D.L `ion` = "interactive on", so the figure stays open and listens for new events